# "which" python3 shows 2 forward slashes in path

Tags: zsh

Just got a new MBP for work and never had this behavior before.

Running

`which python3` or `which python` produces the following:

`/usr/bin//python`
`/usr/bin//python3`

Usually it's simply `/usr/bin/python`

I was having some python (virtualenv) issues which is why I'm researching this.

Comment: What is your `PATH`? I'm guessing it has `/usr/bin/` with a trailing slash. In any case it's not a problem. Consecutive slashes are the same as a single slash.

Comment: I do see a trailing slash in my path for python, although I'm not sure where it's being set. I'm using zsh and nothing is in my .zshrc . I can't figure figure out where that python reference is coming from" `/Users/mbspark/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/mbspark/Library/Python/3.7/bin/`

Comment: Could be down to `which` version / implementation. No matter how many slashes are anywhere in `PATH` and it actually tries to `stat/access` the files with them... mine normalizes the output.

Comment: Huh, `/usr/bin` isn't even in the PATH? That's weird. Is `which` following a symlink or what?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't my full path, that was just showing it does indeed have a trailing slash after bin. `:/usr/bin/:` Now I want to get rid of it!

Comment: Ah, zsh seems to have a built-in `which` that does exactly that: `PATH=/usr/bin/ which python` -> `/usr/bin//python`, try `/usr/bin/which` instead. :)

Comment: @mbspark : Could it be, that your PATH contains `....:/usr/bin/:....`, instead of `....:/usr/bin:....`?

Comment: @user1934428 I think so, but I cannot figure out where to change that. It's not in my bash or zsh profile. It's coming from the system somewhere.

Comment: You are basically setting up your PATH yourself! There are some system wide configuration files which probably set an initial PATH, and indeed /usr/bin is a likely candidate to be set there, but these files are readable: So just check all of them; your zsh _man_ page shows in the section titled _INVOCATION_ all the files which might be relevant. And if you don't like these settings, just write your own in the invocation files in your home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zsh` has its own built-in `which` which does not perform output normalization WRT stripping extra slashes as found in `PATH` environmental variable:

```
$ PATH=/usr/bin which python
/usr/bin/python
```

vs.

```
$ PATH=/usr/bin/ which python
/usr/bin//python

$ PATH=/usr//bin/ which python
/usr//bin//python
```

As opposed to:

```
$ PATH=/usr/bin /usr/bin/which python
/usr/bin/python
$ PATH=/usr/bin/ /usr/bin/which python
/usr/bin/python
$ PATH=/usr//bin/ /usr/bin/which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Gets normalized and yields the same output regarding of what `PATH` was.